# Where is Luke 24:47 referenced in the Old Testament?

Tags: hebrew-bible, luke, intertextuality

According to Luke 24:47. Jesus says "it is written" that "...repentance and remission of sins should be preached in his name"

Where, in the Old Testament, the allusion that **specifically** mentions "repentance and remission of sins" and about them being preached?

Luke 24:45-48 (KJV):

> <sup>45</sup> Then opened he their understanding, that they might understand the scriptures,
> <sup>46</sup> And said unto them, Thus it is written, and thus it behooved Christ to suffer, and to rise from the dead the third day:
> <sup>47</sup> And that repentance and remission of sins should be preached in his name among all nations, beginning at Jerusalem.
> <sup>48</sup> And ye are witnesses of these things.